# insert into select statement inside while loop in sp mysql

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, while-loop

i have a stored procedure where i have a insert into select statement inside a while loop.
the stored procedure is created succesfully but when i execute it it says 0 rows affected.
 with out the while loop for a single data value the sp is returning data. but when the same query is inside a while loop it is returning 0 rows affected.

whats the problem

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE WhileLoopProc1234(INOUT indate DATE,INOUT outdate DATE)
BEGIN
   DECLARE x DATE;
   DECLARE y DATE;
   DECLARE z DATE;

   CREATE TABLE temp2( cardno VARCHAR(10),datevalue DATE );
   SET x = indate;
   SET y = outdate;

   WHILE x!=y DO
      INSERT INTO temp2( cardno,datevalue)
      select CARDNO,x from test_prefixmaster
      where CARDNO not in ( select CARDNO from test_prefixtransactions where    Date(S_DateTime)=x);

     SET x = x + 1;
   END WHILE;

   SELECT * from temp2;

   DROP TABLE temp2;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to avoid doing things the RBAR way in SQL. RBAR(pronounced REEBAR) stands for row by agonizing row. When inserting the data one row at a time of sets of rows one by one you will probably run into serious performance issues later.

I dont have your table structures but I suspect you can change the entire stored procedure to the following and it will be faster and more efficient. If you could please post the CREATE TABLE statements for the tables involved in the query I would be able to make sure that this query is correct. From my understanding you are trying to find CARDNO that does not exist in the test_prefixmaster for a date range.

Thus your entire stored procedure can be made to look as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE WhileLoopProc1234(INOUT indate DATE,INOUT outdate DATE)
BEGIN

   SELECT tst_pfMaster.CARDNO
          ,tst_pfTran.S_DateTime
   FROM test_prefixmaster tst_pfMaster
   LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions  tst_pfTran
        ON tst_pfMaster.CARDNO = tst_pfTran.CARDNO
   WHERE (tst_pfMaster.CARDNO  IS NULL)
         AND (
               (DATE(S_DateTime)>=indate)
               AND (DATE(S_DateTime)<=outdate) 
             )

 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```